# How to increase the Pagination Count (Rows Per Page) for Couch DB?

Tags: couchdb

The maximum pagination count shows as "100" in Couch DB.

That is Rows per page can be set to a maximum of "100"

I have 2000 rows and would like to view the same in the Single Page.

Could you please on how we can change this configuration ???

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about the admin interface? CouchDB views do not limit the number of results they output, you have to specify a `limit` yourself, so that leads me to believe you aren't querying the database yourself.

Comment: Yes, i am not querying but viewing the documents.

Answer (score 0):

per_page display is declared in share\couchdb\www\script\futon.browse.js

update this  per_page: {defaultValue: 10}